# onClick = () => { throws unexpected token error in gulp

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I tried to integrate a react component in my React project. when transpiling with gulp I get an error on line `onClick = () => {`

> js/expanding-animation.js: Unexpected token (14:16)

I am using gulp with babelfy and `"presets": ["react", "es2016"]`

ideas?

```
 import React, {Component} from 'react';

    const animationStyle = {
        transition: 'width 0.75s cubic-bezier(0.000, 0.795, 0.000, 1.000)'
    };

    const makeExpanding = (Target) => {
        return class extends Component {
            constructor(props) {
                super(props);
                this.state = {isOpen: false};
            }

            onClick = () => {
                this.setState({isOpen: !this.state.isOpen});
            };

            render() {
                return (
                    <Target {...this.props}
                            isOpen={this.state.isOpen}
                            onClick={this.onClick}
                            additionalStyles={{text: animationStyle, frame: animationStyle}}/>
                );
            }
        }
    };

    export default makeExpanding;
```

Comment: That's incorrect class syntax, try `onclick () {...funcCode...}` without the closing semi colon `;`

Comment: If you take out that function does it still complain?

Comment: Not related but the title `onClick = () => { throws unexpected token error in gulp` may be invalid format in SO ([How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an experimental feature.

You need to add babel `stage-2` or just to enable this specific feature you can add the following transformation: http://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-class-properties/

```
{
    "presets": ["react", "es2016"],
    "plugins": [
        "transform-class-properties"
    ]
}
```